# Spring Roo Authority Levels

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo, spring-webflow

I have a simple web app i am testing out. It has two levels i.e admin and normal user. The project also has three entities. What i am trying to achieve is an instance where a user cannot delete any entry in the first entity though he can create one.

I believe using @RequestMapping is the way to achieve this but not completely sure how to implement and if not, what other ways are there? A snippet code would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the delete button on your view `jspx` files if you are only blocking the access through the user interface and then disallow calling the delete method through your controllers. You can also use additional methods to restrict users from performing certain operations.

**1. User Interface**

However, you would need to perform a manual check on your controllers to make sure unauthorized users do not perform the delete operation.

Todo this, first you need to import the Spring Security JSP Tag library namespace to your `jspx` file.

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
```

Then use the Spring security tags you just imported to surround the elements which you need to be displayed on the user level.

For an example:

```
   <sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
       <p>User is an administrator</p>
       <!-- Delete button goes here -->
    </sec:authorize>
```

For more information on the tag library, please visit http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html

**2. Controller**

You can intercept the url to disallow users who do not have the `ROLE_ADMIN` by adding the following in your `applicationContext-security.xml`

```
<intercept-url pattern="/countries/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" method="DELETE"/>
```

If it doesn't work for you, try going through the following link.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?123781-intercept-url-method-attribute-not-work-with-put-and-delete

For an interesting tutorial on Spring Security visit http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/petclinic-tutorial.html

Cheers.